# PowerShell equivalent to python read binary file

Tags: powershell, char

I am looking for a way to read in a binary file in Powershell, but my results always have the wrong length.

In Python:

```
with open ("file.txt", "br") as f:
  a = f.read()
len(a)
>> correct size
```

When I try to do this in PowerShell (I used multiple methods, none turned out to be what I needed) I get like 4x the filesize. I tried things like

```
$a = Get-Content 'file.txt' -Encoding Byte
```

But it clearly is not equivalent to my Python command. I basically want to create a set of chars, but only found things on Google like "there is no built in function for this in PowerShell". Meh. Thanks for helping!

**Background**: I want to send a file to an API but I cannot use any other thing than a native PowerShell on win10 to do so. The code in Python works, also if I just use Curl.

I used Fiddler to analyze the body of both (Curl/Python) and the PowerShell attempts, where I can see, that the file I transfer with PowerShell looks very different than the one from being transferred with Curl (headers are the same). So I figured, I might just read in the file in a wrong format leading to the error. Therefore I took the file, read it into Bash/Python and analyzed its length and did the same with PowerShell (file is not a readable Text I must add, but binary data). I soon found out the two files I try to transfer already look very different from each other, which lead me to that exact question posted above.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In this case, some context indicating why you need the result to be in bytes and measured as such would be useful; it's entirely possible that you're overlooking an easier way to accomplish your aim in PowerShell - attempting to do an instruction-for-instruction translation from other scripting languages generally does not use PowerShell's capabilities most effectively.

Comment: I tested both of your code snippets with a text file and a binary file, and got the same value for `len(a)` and `$a.Count` on each occasion.

Comment: $a = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('c:\foo.bin')

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: When I do it with my sample file (*.tar.gz container) it absolutely does not. I failed to mention above, it is not a simple String I am worrying about. Sorry for that.

Comment: Tested with a .tar.gz and still unable to reproduce.

Comment: My file is a *.crt file,  *.info  *.tar.gz file in one container to be specific. That whole thing is then encrypted with a key.

Comment: Well, obviously there's something wrong in the code you're not showing us.